# Optimize blob storage Deltalake using local scope table on Azure Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-lake

How can you optimize an Azure blob storage delta table on Azure Databricks, while not putting the table to a global scope?
Optimizing and z-ordering a delta table on an Azure blob storage can be done via (cf. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-optimize)):

```
spark.sql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T')
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE T USING DELTA LOCATION
          'wasbs://fs@accname.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/df'"
spark.sql('OPTIMIZE T ZORDER BY (colname)')
spark.sql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T')
```

However, the table `T` has a global scope, such that this command fails, if other users have already labeled a table with the name `T`.

A possible solution might be the following, but is this the easiest way (why are `` ` `` needed and not `'`)?

```
spark.sql("OPTIMIZE delta.`wasbs://fs@accname.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/df`
           ZORDER BY (colname)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1. You can & should scope the table to a database. The example above has 'default' as the database name. Just use `MY_DB` as an example:

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE MY_DB.T USING DELTA LOCATION
      'wasbs://fs@accname.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/df'"
```

2. Yes, your suggestion is also correct. The back tics are a weird spark-ism for specifying the LOCATION property of a data set in a select clause.